# How can I copy from Tmux terminal and paste it other application in my OS?

Tags: ubuntu, tmux

I am using tmux on ubuntu. I read this https://awhan.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/copy-paste-in-tmux/ for copy and paste inside tmux. But I would like to know how can I copy from TMUX terminal and paste it to other application e.g browser in my OS?

Comment: If you hold shift when doing a selection, then it does a normal selection rather than a tmux selection.  Then you can copy/paste as normal.  Does that work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tmux by default will "take over" text selection with a mouse, and trigger its own internal selection for use with its own cut and paste.

If you want to use the OS selection, so that you can use the OS cut and paste, hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> while selecting.

Then cut and paste will work normally.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Where did you learn this?

Comment: @glennjackman I think I just assumed there would be a method, and decided that this would be the most likely approach, and tried it :)